# How to display relationships between accounts?

Tags: junction-object

We service many customers. Many of our customers have relationships between themselves, which are important for us to know.

E.g:

A is customer of B, C and D (which on the reverse makes: B,C and D suppliers of A)
B is supplier of A and D (which also makes D a customer of B)

I want to display, for each account, it's suppliers and customer.

If I look on a related list result, it will look like this (for Account 'D')

```
D Customer of B
D Supplier of A
```

For account 'A' it will look like this:

```
A Customer of B
A Customer of C
A Customer of D
```

1. I can use a junction object for this.  (how do I set the reverse names?) - very complicated for managing the complete list.
2. Is there another object way to do it? (appexchange?)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at [Astrea Object Hierarchy](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008ZK9wEAG) which is free in the the App Exchange. It's intended to do exactly what you're asking about in terms of finding up to 2-level hierarchies within a single object. However, I don't believe it's designed to display things in a parent, grandparent context, but perhaps that might be a paid option that might be well worth the price. In any case, it clearly will get you at least half way to the solving the the problem at hand.

Comment: Thank you. It's not what I am looking for - looking for a two-way-indication of relationships